# Pages are showing "The page you requested does not exist", but when I view content I can edit the page, but unable to view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am unable to view a page from within the site. It is not occurring on all pages, just some, with no commonality. If you view the page, it says that the page does not exist. When you go into the content, and view the page from the drupal admin backend, you can "edit" the page, and view all the content perfectly.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: What are the pages about (nodes, views, custom pages)? What are the paths? Did you use pathauto or a similar module for the paths and you are now requesting the old paths?

Comment: They are nodes (basic pages). The site is setup to use pathauto. 

Thanks

Comment: Disable pathauto module and caches for a while, clear all caches and see if it happens again. There may be so many reasons for this happening so you better provide more information about the problem, such as modules that may be related (display, access permissions, paths, cache etc) and when this problem started (eg after a module installation).

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a Node, look at the URL in your Browser. There must something like node/nodeID/edit, e.g. node/7/edit.

Can you access the page if you call node/nodeId eg node/7 ?

Second Point are the Permissions, go to Users -> Permissions, there are Permissions like "Views Page Content of Type article". Are this permissions set correctly?

Comment: Thank you for the tips. When viewing the page from the node, it redirects you to the alias name, instead of the node. The pages that I am trying to view are basic pages. 

I have also gone through the settings for permissions and nothing has changed.

Comment: disable the pathauto module for a time and test it again

Answer (score 0):

...and if you used the Panels module for custom pages, be sure they are actually "enabled"